# how to get the href value of anchor on a keypress?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using keydown for distinct result as said in jquery library. i am trying to get the anchor href value when user press `a` key. keydown event with a `e.which` code of `65`

I'm not getting the value. What is the problem here. Any idea?

CODE

HTML

```
<a href="http://stack" class="hrefval">anchor</a>
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(window).keydown(function(e) {
         if(e.which == '65'){
          //  alert('test');
            alert($('a.hrefval').attr(href));
    }
    });
});
```

[**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/5YvYY/)

Comment: [Learn how to](http://www.creativebloq.com/javascript/javascript-debugging-beginners-3122820) [**debug** JavaScript](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/javascript-debugging). The console clearly shows `Uncaught ReferenceError: href is not defined`.

Comment: Thanks for the debug and sorry for the small mistake. Should i accept the answer or should i delete? @Felix Kling

Comment: Accept the answer that helped you the most.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to pass `href` in quotes `''`

```
alert($('a.hrefval').attr('href'));
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/GWUwJ/)

In your current code its looking for variable `href` which is undefined thus you are not getting an output. If you look at you console you will be getting an error such as

> Uncaught ReferenceError: href is not defined

Answer (score 2):

You are missing the quotes in `.attr()`. Use:

```
alert($('a.hrefval').attr('href'));
```

**[Working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/5YvYY/1/)**

Answer (score 0):

you can try also `alert($('a.hrefval').prop('href'));`

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).on('keydown',function(e) {
        //console.log(e);
        if(e.keyCode == '65'){
          //  alert('test');
            alert($('.hrefval').attr('href'));
    }
    });
});
```